# XML escape characters are treated as literals in ExeCommand

Tags: wix, custom-action

Within a [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) setup (being a beginner in that regard) I'm trying to uncompress a zip archive as [`CustomAction`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) with `ExeCommand` using Powershell (PS5, .NET >4.5 installed).

```
<CustomAction Id='UncompressZipFile' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' Execute='immediate'
              ExeCommand='powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command &quot;Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [\[]IO.Compression.ZipFile[\]]::ExtractToDirectory(&apos;foo.zip&apos;, &apos;.&apos;);&quot;'
              Return='check'/>
```

Powershell is invoked correctly, however it tries to interpret `&quot;` and therefore throws an exception. This means the esacpe characters are forwarded as literals by WiX. However, seemingly all of the WiX examples for `CustomAction` are using escape characters.

**Are there WiX setting(s) I am missing which controls how XML escape characters are treated or have influence on those?**

---

The following works though this is not valid XML (`"` and `'` are not escaped).

```
<!--
The separate variable for Powershell command call is needed for quote
characters, since the escape characters (&amp;, &quot;, &apos; etc) are
forwarded as literals to Powershell (reason unknown).
-->
<?define psUnzipCmd = "Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [\[]IO.Compression.ZipFile[\]]::ExtractToDirectory('foo.zip', '.');" ?>
<CustomAction Id='UncompressZipFile' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' Execute='immediate'
              ExeCommand='powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "$(var.psUnzipCmd)"'
              Return='check'/>
```

---

I know it is bad to use a zip in an installation for several reasons. However in this specific case I'm dealing with 100k+ of very small files and a lot of folders, which change often. Windows installer upgrade/change/repair are not used.

Comment: I wonder if heat can handle harvesting a folder with that many files

Comment: It does, however every file is also registered as a single component. Therefore the deinstallation takes very long. Using heat with an XSLT to combine several files into one component might be a solution, however upgrade, repair etc is not needed for that application anyway.